# Is dynamic memory destroyed when static object is destroyed?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Taking a look to the following code snippet:

```
//A.h
class A
{
  void f();
};

//A.cpp
#include "A.h"

void A:f()
{
  map<string, string> *ThisMap = new map<string, string>;

  //more code (a delete will not appear)
}

//main.cpp
#include "A.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  A object;

  object.f();

  //more code (a delete will not appear)

  return 0;
}
```

When main() ends it execution, object will be destroyed. Would be destroyed dinamic allocated memory asigned to ThisMap too?

Comment: Yes `object` will be destructed and removed from memory. ***However*** the memory you allocated inside `A::f` will *not* be deallocated (by your program) so you will have a memory leak. Rule of thumb: `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: Where is the static object?

Comment: Aside from that, it's often very unusual to dynamically allocate standard containers, and in most cases it's really not needed. If, for some reason, it *is* needed then use e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Ok! Thanks! In this case I cannot modify the code, I'm doing testing of it and CppUTest doesn't report me a leak. I put a similar snippet and std::unique_ptr is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would be destroyed dinamic allocated memory asigned to ThisMap too?

*No*!

You have a memory leak, since `object` gets destroyed, its destructor gets called, but no `delete` is called for your map.

Pro-tip: `delete` whatever you `new`'ed, when you are done with it.

---

PS: I highly doubt it that you need to dynamic allocate a standard container (like `std::map`), but if you really are sure that you need to use, then consider using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/).

Answer (score 0):

> Would be destroyed dinamic allocated memory asigned to ThisMap too?

No, the rule of thumb before C++11 was that if you `new` something, you must `delete` it later.

Since C++11, you are very strongly encouraged to use *smart pointers*, which deal with allocation/deallocation for you in a safe manner. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)'s documentation is a good starting point.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! In this case I cannot modify the code, I'm doing testing of it and CppUTest doesn't report me a leak. I put a similar snippet and std::unique_ptr is not used.

Answer (score 0):

No. 
1. If you want `ThisMap` to be A's data field, you have to declare and implement your own destructor, so your code should be like:

```
class A
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> *ThisMap;
  void f();
  ~A();
};

void A::f()
{
  ThisMap = new map<std::string, std::string>;

  //more code (a delete will not appear)
}
A::~A()
{
  if(ThisMap) delete ThisMap;
}
```

2. If ThisMap is just a function variable, so you just have to delete it at the end of the use, like:

```
void A::f()
{
  map<string, string> *ThisMap = new map<std::string, std::string>;
  //more code (a delete will not appear)
  delete ThisMap;
}
```

Notice that its `A::f` and not `A:f`
:)